# Finding a bound for $|g(x)-g(p)|$. Why are these hypotheses necesary?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

I was looking at the following question from Numerical Analysis. I think I solved it, but I don't see why we need two of the hypotheses. I was wondering, are my solutions incorrect, or is there a more standard way to solve it, which would make use of the hypotheses?

$$\begin{matrix}
\\
\end{matrix}$$

> Let $g \in C^2([a, b])$ and $p \in (a, b)$ with $g(p)=p$, $g'(p)=0$, $g''(p) \not = 0$.
>
> $a)$ Show that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for all $x \in [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]$, we have $g^n(x) \to p$ as $n \to \infty$. [I assume $g^n(x)$ refers to function composition here.]
>
> $b)$ With $\epsilon$ as in part $(a)$, show that for all  $x \in [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]$, we have $|g(x) - p| \le M|x-p|^2$, where $M = \dfrac {1}{2} \max_{x \in [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]}|g''(x)|.$

$$\begin{matrix}
\\
\end{matrix}$$

First, I do not think we need $g''(p) \not = 0$ for either of the parts. Second, for part $b$, I don't think we need $x\in [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]$. I think $x$ can be anywhere in $[a, b]$.

$$\begin{matrix}
\\
\\
\end{matrix}$$

**Solution for Part a**

We are given that $p$ is a fixed point of $g$. Since $g'(p) = 0$ and $g$ is continuous, there is an interval $[p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]$ where $|g'| < \frac 12$. By the MVT, it follows that $\forall x, y \in [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]: |g(x) - g(y)| \le \frac 12 |x-y|$, so $g$ is a contraction map. Therefore, by the Contraction Mapping Theorem, for any $x$ in the interval, the sequence $g^n(x)$ converges to the fixed point $p$, as desired.

**Solution for Part b**

Let $x \in [a, b]$. We can expand $g$ as a series around $p$ as
$$g(x) = g(p) + g'(p) (x-p) + \dfrac{g''(\xi)}{2} (x-p)^2.$$
Using $g(p) = p$, $g'(p)=0$, and rearranging, we get

$$|g(p)-p| \le \dfrac M2|x-p|^2$$
as desired.

Comment: You get in b) quadratic convergence of $g^n(x)$ only for $M|x-p|<1$. If you compute the maximum of $g''$ over a larger interval, then $M$ becomes larger and thus the interval for the quadratic convergence smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need $g''(p) \not = 0$ anywhere. It is not an error on the part of your teacher to include the condition $g''(p) \not = 0$. In the (exceedingly rare) event that $g''(p) = 0$ you will have cubic convergence, but outside the classroom, quadratic convergence is as good as it gets.

However, (for part b) you have no control of $g''(\xi)$, unless $x \in I = [p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon]$. By Taylor's formula $\xi$ is *between* the expansion point $p$ and the point $x$. If $x \in I$, then $\xi$ is also in $I$, because $I$ is an interval. This is why you know with certainty that $|g''(\xi)| \leq M$.